# How to convert the following time string of days to hours?

Tags: python-3.x, string, datetime, awk, sed

```
x1 , y1 , 3 days 05:30:06.96 , 3 days 06:00:01.96
x2 , y2 , 3 days 05:30:06.96 , 3 days 06:31:16.96
```

I want to convert the above csv to

```
x1 , y1 , 77:30:06.96 , 78:00:01.96
x2 , y2 , 77:30:06.96 , 78:31:16.96
```

essentially convert "3 days" to 72 hours and add it to hours column (72+5)

what is a nifty way of achieving this either in python or using unix utilities?

Doesn't look like python  datetime.strptime() has an option to pattern match the "3 days" part.

Comment: Seems like you're dealing with duration (timedelta), not datetime. Although pandas might be overkill depending on the rest of your application, [to_timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) would parse those strings. The formatting from timedelta back to string would still be up to you.

Comment: I suggest to take a look at `awk`: `awk -F ' , | |:' '{print $1,$2,$3*24+$5,$6,$7,$8*24+$10,$11,$12}' file`

Comment: Thanks for the response. will check out to_timedelta , was trying to avoid pandas so far may be chunking data using data frames probably is more efficient instead of using dicts.Will check out the awk option. sed below seems to be super elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if there are no utilities that conform to this pattern, you can easily make do it yourself. I doubt that you can find a nice, nifty one-liner to do this very easily without some deep research, and even then you may not come across it. Assuming that there are three columns, separated by commas, you can use the split method of the string to separate it into a list of four. Then you can use split again with a space delimiter to access the third and fourth column components and do the math yourself.

```
def calc_time(time_str):
    ''' time_str in the format of: # days #:#:#.# '''
    data = time_str.split()
    # column 3 (index 2) should contain the : separated time
    time_data = data[2].split(':')

    # Multiplying days by 24 hours and adding extra hours
    total_hour = int(data[0]) * 24 + int(time_data[0])
    
    time_data[0] = str(total_hour)

    # time_data is the : separated time, which now contains the hours + days
    return ':'.join(time_data)

line = 'x1 , y1 , 3 days 05:30:06.96 , 3 days 06:00:01.96'
data = line.split(',')
# data should be a list of 4 strings now
data[2] = ' ' + calc_time(data[2])
data[3] = ' ' + calc_time(data[3])

result = ','.join(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/ (\S+) days (..)/ $((\1*24+10#\2))/g;s/.*/echo "&"/e' file
```

Replace days and hours by a bash computation and use echo to evaluate the result.

Comment: Works pretty well except for error when it encounters "09" , treating the number as octal. with 10# in front of 09 , is doing the job. Thanks!    sed -E 's/ (\S+) days (..)/ $((\1*24+10#\2))/g;s/.*/echo "&"/e'